# Mod_Pagespeed? Configuration OK but report not

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

Here is my configurations;

```
Here is my configuration for http://181.224.129.45/ 

ModPagespeed On
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
ModPagespeedProgressiveJpegMinBytes 2048
ModPagespeedJpegRecompressionQualityForSmallScreens 70
ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_rendered_image_dimensions
ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_jpeg 
ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_png
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters jpeg_subsampling
ModPagespeedEnableFilters strip_image_meta_data
ModPagespeedEnableFilters strip_image_color_profile
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_gif_to_png
ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_style_attributes
ModPagespeedEnableFilters local_storage_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_domains
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_google_font_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_meta_tags
ModPagespeedEnableFilters add_head
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,sprite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_preview_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters defer_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_meta_tags
ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_above_scripts
ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch
ModPagespeedEnableFilters canonicalize_javascript_libraries
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,rewrite_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_css,inline_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_quotes
ModPagespeedFileCacheSizeKb 102400
ModPagespeedFileCacheCleanIntervalMs 3600000
ModPagespeedLRUCacheKbPerProcess 1024
ModPagespeedLRUCacheByteLimit 16384
ModPagespeedCssInlineMaxBytes 2048
ModPagespeedImageInlineMaxBytes 2048
ModPagespeedCssImageInlineMaxBytes 2048
ModPagespeedJsInlineMaxBytes 2048
ModPagespeedCssOutlineMinBytes 3000
ModPagespeedJsOutlineMinBytes 3000
```

This configuration does not breaks anything. When i want to use `insert_image_dimensions`site breaks and images are shrinking. Kinda funny though,
Whatever my point is 41 for that ip. It will be raise when i activate cloudflare for sure but i have a customer that insisting pagespeed results must be great. I think im gonna kill him.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the CoreFilters set? You need `ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough` in there somewhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi from the mod_pagespeed team.  The insert_image_dimensions filter is not in the core set for a reason: depending on the CSS it can break page layout.

That super-long list of filters looks hard to maintain.  Are you sure you don't want to use rewrite_images (which includes many of those) or even "ModPagespeedRewriteLevel CoreFilters, which covers even more.  One thing missing from your set is convert_jpeg_to_webp which can reduce image size significantly for compatible browers (Android, Chrome and Opera).

The PageSpeed Insights tool and score help guide you to make specific improvements.  But to measure performance I'd start with www.webpagetest.org, selecting a geography and connection speed that makes sense for your users.  But the best approach is to measure live traffic (RUM).  mod_pagespeed's add_instrumentation filter provides a very basic form of this, but there are plenty of RUM products which are designed for this, including Google Analytics, Soasta, and many others.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't kill anyone
2. Optimize the page as much as you can manually, by editing your template. Only as a final step, you might want to add certain boost with a few mod_pagespeed filters, like converting small png's to data:, inlining small css etc. But in any case - don't go crazy with all that if the page load fits into 2 seconds or so.
3. Explain to the customer that in the end what matters is not the PageSpeed score but user experience - that is what will give him sales, not the score.

Re. image dimensions in particular - certain designs, especially responsive explicitly need image dimensions NOT to be set. Standards are changing and improving all the time as technology progresses. So don't look at all that as super strict rules but rather as recommendations.

Comment: That's bad advice. The PageSpeed scores are an indication of how Google sees your site. In relative terms to your competitors, those with the better scores will be better positioned in search results for equivalent terms. So when you're making a claim about "sales" -- better SEO  == more sales.

Comment: I don't quite see why it is a bad advice and I am not making any claims. The question is about mod_pagespeed which is Google's product. Unless you are a Google intern you really have no way to know how exactly G classifies site ranking factors. Also better SEO does not equal more sales. The factors that convert a visitor into a customer are many and SERP position is definitely not the only (or main) one.

Comment: "better SEO does not equal more sales" <-- this is just plain bad logic. No matter your conversion rate, if you have more visitors coming to your site sales will go up. Better SEPR == more visitor.

Answer (score 1):

This is all I use ( note for nginx, but same filters... )

```
    pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace;
    pagespeed EnableFilters remove_comments;
    pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
    pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_css;
    pagespeed EnableFilters sprite_images;
    pagespeed EnableFilters defer_javascript;
    pagespeed EnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch;
```

backed by memcache

It works fine for me on a demo 1.9 site install